# Google App script: Stumped on command to extract 'title' from forum HTML page & paste into a spreadsheet (my code inside)

Tags: xml-parsing, google-apps-script

I'm Extremely new to this and I've been trying to get the `title` of each unique forum page (or topic) here is the code I have so far:

```
function GraalGet() {
//parses forums for ALL posts one by one, extract <title> from HTML webpage 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var i = 31
 var url = "http://www.graalians.com/forums/showthread.php?p="+i;

  //var params = {method : "post"}; can this be used at all?
  //The aim: loop this once you can get 1 result.

 var geturl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(); //maybe .getContentText should be elsewhere? 
 var parseurl = Xml.parse(geturl, true);               //confirmed - this is true because it wont parse HTML if false
 var titleinfo = parseurl.getElement().getElement("html"); //.getElement('body');//.getElements("title");

 sheet.appendRow([titleinfo, i]);
}
```

In addition the script would write down the topic number in the adjoining cell. 
There's a lot of answered questions about extracting XML data, and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711937/finding-elements-after-a-urlfetch) is about parsing HTML but I couldn't pull up any results - I'm honestly stumped and any help about finding and extracting the  tag will be appreciated. (If you have the time, please feel free to explain as well, but I'll be thankful for any help really.)

For reference I have used these:

- [Google's Kevin Bacon Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/XML_tutorial)
- [The authors comments on bugs with the script & some explanation](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/jlFsJIRcPhw)

I'm sorry if I'm being pedantic, this is my first post & I don't want to anger anyone,  please do tell me if I've broken any rules, I'll do my best to fix them. I've left the comments I made for myself for your perusal too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Logger.log to print out debugging information. I did this with your function and figured out that the title tag is embedded within the  tag. So you should use something like this. Also, getElement returns an XmlElement object which you should convert to String using getText().

```
var titleinfo = parseurl.getElement().getElement('head').getElement('title'); 
sheet.appendRow([titleinfo.getText(), i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly! So does that mean that for whatever element I want to extract data from, I will have to just keep on adding parseurl.getElement() till I reach the specific element I need? Also Thank you so much for the .getText() example - THAT was the missing sauce I needed!

Comment: Yes, you add getElement() once for each nested element. If this worked, can you consider accepting the answer

Comment: Sorry, I've been hacking away and totally forgot to update this! 
Sadly I can't understand how to get beyond the first DIV (I was aiming to get to the topic title which is encased within <strong></strong> tags nested deep withing the page,  it just produced an error at the first .getElement('div') it encountered. Regardless, Thank you so much for helping!